# Get the sum per date of nested objects in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, sum

I have an array with nested objects that looks like the one below.
What I'd like to do is loop through it calculate the sum of each item per date.

For example pc + screen = ?

I cannot seem to figure out how to do it properly. I have found this solution, it works great in console.log() but I cannot figure out how to output the result in a div. Should I use a map function ?

```
  const amountPerDate = data.forEach(function (i) {
    const sum = i.item.reduce(function (sum, elem) {
      return sum + elem.price;
    }, 0);
    console.log("the total sum is " + sum);
  });
```

The array:

[image: Array]

Comment: If you have a `<div id="total"></div>` then `document.getElementById('#total').textContent = sum` or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted doesn't seem quite right since `forEach` won't return anything, and the inner variable `sum` is not actually available for React to render since it is not in scope (in JavaScript, variables can not escape their containing function, which is `function (i) {` -- nothing outside of that function can see it).

You were roughly on the right tracks with needing `map` since that will return an array that represents an accumulation of the return values in the nested callback.

```
 const amountsPerDate = data.map((i) => {
    return i.item.reduce(function (sum, elem) {
      return sum + elem.price;
    }, 0);
  });
```

`amountsPerDate` will now be an array of the sums. However, in this process, youve lost the info about which sum correlates to which date. So we need more. We can modify to return both the sum alongside the date (an array of objects, each with a sum and date inside).

```
 const amountsPerDate = data.map((i) => {
    return {
       sum: i.item.reduce(function (sum, elem) {
           return sum + elem.price;
       }, 0),
       date: i.date
  });
```

Now, you should have something in `amountsPerDate` that looks like this:

```
[
    { date: '01/01/2022', sum: 200 },
    { date: '02/01/2022', sum: 30},
]
```

To display in your react component, it's just a case of rendering it, which will require you to map over this new data and return an element for each entry. You haven't posted your full component, but it will be something like this in your JSX:

```
<div>
    {amountsPerDate.map(sum => 
         <div>Date: {sum.date}. Total: {sum.sum}</div>
    )}
</div>
```

Of course you can play with this and move it around as you see fit so it fits however you want it laid out.

It's really worth your time understanding `map` and the differences with `foreach` since it's so ubiquitous in functional programming. Foreach and map both loop over each item. But map allows you to return a value within the loop callback, and that value goes on to be part of a new array returned from `map` that represents that item. You can think of it as a transformation from one array to another -- both with the same length -- but with each item replaced with something of your choosing, calculated from each items original contents.

Comment: This is perfect ! very well explained. 

I'd make a small mod to this and also create an object for the products, this way when I try to output them in a card, I'll have the Date, The total price, and all the items related to that date and their price by unit

Comment: Yep that should work fine! Would you mind marking as accepted if it helped :)

Comment: No worries! Just one additional tip. It barely matters here cos the data is so small, but if this dataset gets large you might want to look into `useMemo` so that it doesnt end up doing the math on every render. Again, this is a relatively trivial amount of math unless your talking about thousands (even tens of thousands/hundreds of thousands) of items, but each time you do this sort of thing you should consider the perf impact, which `useMemo` can mitigate.

Comment: I'm still learning the basics and working just with small datasets but thanks for the tip.